# How to get HTMLElement of Input Event in form.valuechanges.subscribe()?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am rewriting my code because this code doesn't work when using IPAD.
so I thought I should use this.form.valuechanges() instead of change event.

but I am stuck because I don't know how to manipulate DOM inside valuechanges.subscribe().

When value in text area has changed, td background color also changes to different color.

so I want to do same thing inside this.form.valuechanges.subscribe().

I can get event object inside table. but I can't get event object inside this.form.valuechanges.subscribe((val) => { }).

Case 1: using change event (this is what I want to do)

HTML

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index" class="column-order">
    <mat-form-field class="not-fix-width text-right" [formGroupName]="index">
        <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            (change)="valueChanged(element, $event, $event.target.value)"
            formControlName="order"
        />
    </mat-form-field>
</td>
```

Component

```
constructor(
    private platform: Platform, 
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, 
    private renderer: Renderer2) {}

valueChanged(parameter: any, event: any, order: string) {
    const copy = this.dataSource.data().slice();
    order = this.checkValue(order);
    parameter.order = order;
    this.dataUpdate(copy);
    // compare before value and after value
    if (this.isSameOldValue(parameter['name'], order)) { 
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.getHtmlElement(event.srcElement.parentElement), 'coloredBackground');
    } else {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.getHtmlElement(event.srcElement.parentElement), 'coloredBackground');
    }
}

getHtmlElement(elem: HTMLElement) {
    if (elem.parentElement.nodeName === 'TD') {
        return elem.parentElement;
    } else {
        return this.getHtmlElement(elem.parentElement);
    }
}

dataUpdate(copy: Param[]) {
    this.dataSource.update(copy);
    this.edited.emit({
        parameters: this.dataSource.data().slice(),
        code: this.value.code,
        index: this.index,
        invalid: this.form.invalid,
    });
 }
```

Case 2: using valuechanges method (I think this is better way)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.form.valueChanges
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$))
      .subscribe((nowValue) => {
         // compare before value and after value
         // make flag for visible/invisible save button
         // this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
      });
}
```

Comment: is your form property a FormGroup / FormControl? if not, in order to get reactive forms you should consider this -> https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: my form is FormGroup. Top FormGroup have FormArray of FormGroup.